# How to know if the browser has lost focus

Tags: javascript, focus, onblur

I've tried using onblur for my problem, but that only is if the focus changes from one textbox to another or something similar. I am writing a webpage for an embedded browser that has several issues. When the browser is hidden a gif is not being hidden, and seems like it stays in cache. My thinking is perhaps there is a way to invoke the browser to hide the gif as the focus is lost. Focus in this case would be similar to a user clicking on another window. This seems like it is out of the scope of web technologies, but I thought I'd ask.

Thanks!

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active).

Hope it helps.

Comment: You don't. Certain things have been disallowed for privacy reasons.